# Program to restrict object creation in Python

Tags: python, oop

```
class object_restrict(object):
    _count = 0

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._count > 5:
            raise TypeError("Too many keys created")

        cls._count += 1
        print "object created"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

k = object_restrict()
k1 = object_restrict()
k2 = object_restrict()
k3 = object_restrict()
k4 = object_restrict()
k5 = object_restrict()
```

It seems I have some questions regarding how can we restrict the number of objects for a class in Python. I have been asked to write a program where I should put the condition where we can create only 5 instances of a class, and if we try to create more than 5, it should raise an exception.

As we know in Python, `__new__` is the method which is get called whenever an instance needs to be created. I tried to write some code, but it didn't work.

When I ran this code, it ran for all 6 times. Please can somebody guide me here? I also tried checking on Google but didn't get any proper code.

Comment: Post your code as code, not as a picture.

Comment: Try creating a 7th object.

Comment: i a trying to post the code but it giving me error so again posted as image

Comment: I answered to your question.

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out by [Wilfred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43324458/5348860) there's a problem with the `_count` check or variable initialization. but i would like to point out another problem which is that you are not returning the instance of the object. if you have this:

```
class A(object):

    _count = 0 

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._count > 5:
            raise Exception('Too many instances were created')
        cls._count += 1

    def __init__(self):
        pass

asd = A() 
print asd
```

will output:

```
$ None
```

you should return the instance of the object, which is actually `__new__` responsibility:

```
class A(object):

    _count = 0 

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._count >= 5:  # @Wilfred fix
            raise Exception('Too many instances were created')
        cls._count += 1
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)  # returning the instance

    def __init__(self):
        pass

asd = A() 
print asd
```

output:

```
$ <__main__.A object at 0x7f5ddad7db10>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class object_restrict(object):
    _count = 0

    def __new__(cls):
        cls._count += 1
        if cls._count > 5:
            raise TypeError("Too many keys created")

        print cls._count, "object created"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

k = object_restrict()
k1 = object_restrict()
k2 = object_restrict()
k3 = object_restrict()
k4 = object_restrict()
k5 = object_restrict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You init your _count variable to 0.

First call : `_count = 0`

Sixth call : `_count = 5`, So he can create your object.

Init `_count = 1` or update your if condition to `cls._count >= 5:`

Comment: Glad to help you. Don't forget to accept this anwser ;)

Answer (score 0):

A class that allows maximum 5 objects to be instantiated (Python 3):

```
class RestrictClass(object):
    __count = 0
    def __new__(cls):
        if cls.__count>=5:
            raise TypeError("Already instantiated")
        cls.__count+=1
        return super(RestrictClass,cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def showNumberOfObjects(self):
        print("Number of objects are now: "+str(self.__count))


k1 = RestrictClass()
k1.showNumberOfObjects()
k2 = RestrictClass()
k2.showNumberOfObjects()
k3 = RestrictClass()
k3.showNumberOfObjects()
k4 = RestrictClass()
k4.showNumberOfObjects()
k5 = RestrictClass()
k5.showNumberOfObjects()
k6 = RestrictClass()
k6.showNumberOfObjects()
```

Output:

```
Number of objects are now: 1
Number of objects are now: 2
Number of objects are now: 3
Number of objects are now: 4
Number of objects are now: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/arsho/Documents/pyPrac/object.py", line 27, in <module>
    k6 = RestrictClass()
  File "/media/arsho/Documents/pyPrac/object.py", line 5, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Already instantiated")
TypeError: Already instantiated
```

Comment: there's no need for the `else` clause.